# How does this phoneme inventory look?

Tags: conlang-creation, phonetics

How does this phoneme inventory look and any roles for them? Like, how should these be used, what they look like, and how hard it may be for people to comprehend:

a - [a]

ā - [aː]

å - [ø]

ä - [ɛ/ɑ]

â - [ɒ]

æ - [æ]

b - [b]

c - [k/ɡ/t͡s]

č - [ʧ/t͡ɕ]

ç - [ɕ/s]

d - [d]

ð - [ð]

e - [e/ɛ]

ē - [eː/i]

ë - [ɘ]

ə - [ə]

f - [f/ɸ]

g - [ɡ]

ğ - [ɣ/ʁ]

h - [h]

ĥ - [χ/x]

i - [i]

ı - [ɨ]

ī - [iː]

ï - [ɨ/i]

j - [ʤ/j/i]

ĵ - [ʒ]

k - [k]

l - [l/ɫ]

ł - [ɫ]

m - [m]

n - [n]

ñ - [ɲ]

ŋ - [ŋ]

o - [o]

ō - [oː]

ô - [ɔ]

œ - [œ]

p - [p/ɸ]

q - [q/kw/kʷ]

ĸ - [q]

r - [r/ɾ]

s - [s]

š - [ʃ]

t - [t]

u - [u/ʊ]

ū - [uː]

ü - [ʏ/u]

v - [v]

w - [w/u/ʊ]

ŵ - [ʋ]

x - [ks/x/χ]

y - [y/i/j]

z - [z]

ž - [ʒ]

þ - [θ]

& - —

The alphabet itself:
a ā å ä â æ b c č ç d ð e ē ë ə f g ğ h ĥ i ı ī ï j ĵ k l ł m n ñ ŋ o ō ô œ p q ĸ r s š t u ū ü v w ŵ x y z ž þ &

All letter categories:

Vowels:
a ā å ä â æ e ē ë ə i ı ī ï o ō ô œ u ū ü

Consonants:
b c č ç d ð f g ğ h ĥ ĵ k l ł m n ñ ŋ p q ĸ r s š t v ŵ x z ž þ

Semivowels:
j w y

Other:
&

EDIT: Draconis recommended me to include a spreadsheet, so here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1V8HTUVOvpst9fFIOds_u27ue9JbeXOGjU2ns2JA6viY/htmlview

[image: Pie chart.]

Pie chart of every letter category, with each category shown as the first letter in it.

Comment: Do the slashes mean indecision about how to pronounce a letter?  Or perhaps the pronunciation of ‹x› depends on a word's origin?

Comment: Depends on the purpose of your conlang.  If it's intended to be an "easily pronounceable" international auxiliary languages, then at least half of those phonemes need to go.  But as the language of a fictional country, it's at least plausible.

Comment: Please stop doing minor edits every day that do no substantially improve this question. When you want to attract more attention to your question, you have several possibilities, like sharing a link to the question on social media or other site, or announcing a bounty when you have enough reputation.

Comment: @SirCornflakes The minor edits are due to the fluctuation of the alphabet, and as for the edits themselves, they thankfully have gone away.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Nevermind, I added a tag I shouldn't have so I removed the tag.

Comment: @SirCornflakes And I added a pie chart for detail. Truly sorry.

Comment: @SirCornflakes And I decided to make a larger edit by adding uppercase.

Comment: @SirCornflakes [unnatural-features] tag was readded. Will be the last time I edit this.

Comment: There is nothing unnatural about that phoneme inventory (maybe except the collision of [ɘ] and [ə]), c.f. the example of Danish quoted in the answer.

Comment: And again, the edits are annoying for the users here watching the "active questions". At the end of the day, this is a question-and-answer site for third party users to step by and look at. It is not a place to deposit documentation of a conlang (consider setting up a personal website for that purpose).

Comment: @SirCornflakes You're lucky, the edits are over.

Comment: @SirCornflakes "Nothing unusual" — what do you mean by unusual? Sure, the phonemes of "ë" and "ə" may be unusual, but why are you excluding "&"?! It's exactly what it looks like!

Comment: & is not a phoneme, it is just a grapheme (presumably for the word "and"), and it spells out the three phonemes (or two, when a diphthong is considered one phoneme instead of two) /k/ /a/ /i/ (or /k/ /ai/).

Comment: @SirCornflakes Yes, but in my conlang, the ampersand _&_ functions as both a logogram for a word AND a letter. Although it's RARELY used in words. And since there's no uppercase nor lowercase, it's the only unicameral letter. It therefore combines a logogram and a letter into a single mess of a grapheme.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Actually, the ampersand _&_ in my conlang now has the same purpose as it does in English, French, and every other language that uses it: replacing "and".

Comment: Everyone, including @SirCornflakes, this is the TRUE last time I edit... as for the pie chart, the extra "b" is a mistake. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Edit reverted because the new figure was broken (at least on my screen). P.S. It is somewhat hidden, but [this piece of help](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) says: (Reasons to reject a suggested edit): No improvement whatsoever

  *  changes to content or formatting that are unnecessary or make the post more confusing
 *   changes to grammar, spelling, or style that are unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thirteen vowel qualities (if I counted correctly) is a lot and makes the language hard to learn, but it is not outside the range some Germanic languages offer, I think specifically of the case of Danish here. Having two central vowels, ë - [ɘ] and ə - [ə], is probably a challenge, their coocurrence in one language is really rare. Giving them a bit more distance, e.g., by replacing [ə] with [ɜ], can help here.

The consonant system is not overly ambitious, it may provide some difficulties depending on the native language of the learners, the th's or the h-like sounds may be some obstacles.

Comment: But what about that one in between Thorn and the glottal stop, as well as the one AFTER the glottal stop (a.k.a. the last one.)

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear Those aren't phonemes, they're letters.

Comment: @Draconis The alphabet was changed for the true LAST time. Anyways, I meant that letter that's this... thing: &

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear Still not a phoneme I'm afraid.

Comment: @Draconis But it represents the [kai] sound as shown on the list.

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear [kai] is not a phoneme.

Comment: @Draconis Do you have _anything_ to say about the letter shown as a literal _& sign_? In fact, does _anyone_ have to say anything about that?

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear It's a letter, not a phoneme, and this is a question about a phoneme inventory. I'm not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151238/discussion-between-thesmartwaterbear-and-draconis).

Answer (score 4):

The most important point is, this isn't a phoneme inventory! It's an orthography. When you list multiple pronunciations for a letter, especially in brackets `[]` rather than slashes `//`, it's not clear if you want those to be separate phonemes, or different realizations of the same phoneme.

I'd recommend writing down a list of the *phonemes* specifically (with the orthography in parentheses if you really want to include it) and putting them in a table, [like you'd find on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language#Phonology). Any spreadsheet program (Excel, Calc, Google Sheets, etc) can make something like that.

The table will let you see whether there are any weird asymmetries, or whether any part of the consonant or vowel space is getting too crowded.

Comment: I already did that here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V8HTUVOvpst9fFIOds_u27ue9JbeXOGjU2ns2JA6viY/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: As for multiple pronunciations, yes, they DO show separate phonemes in themselves.

Comment: @thesmartwaterbear In that case, I'd recommend putting that into the question!